# Django get object with most references from other

Tags: django

I'm currently doing a little project in Django. The idea is that I have a model for Supervisors and Projects, the supervisor model contains details such as first and last name, email etc. And the project model contains a subject, description, publish date and a deadline etc.

```
class Supervisor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Project(models.Model):
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(Supervisor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get the a list of supervisors with the most projects, and eventually only count projects that aren't past the deadline (Active projects). This in the same view as a list over projects.

So far what I have is:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects.order_by('-pub_date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['supervisor_list'] = Supervisor.objects.annotate(num_projects=Count('Project')).order_by('-num_projects')[0:5]
        return context
```

I get an FieldError saying it can't resolve the keyword 'Project'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `Count('Project')` to `Count('project')` will resolve the exception you get.

To get top 5 supervisors with active projects, add filter by project deadline:

```
from django.utils import timezone

supervisors = Supervisor.objects \
                        .filter(project__deadline__gte=timezone.now()) \
                        .annotate(num_projects=Count('project')) \
                        .order_by('-num_projects')[:5]
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked after I imported the timezone module from utils.